# Flask POST Method Not being Allowed. Not allowed on the URL

Tags: python, json, api, flask, methods

I've been trying to push some data which was fed to a machine learning and been trying to show the results on screen however no matter what I try I can't seem to be able to dodge this error.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])


#@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])


def predict():

   
 if request.method == 'POST' or 'GET':
        try:
          json_ = request.json
          print(json_)
          query = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(json_))
          query = query.reindex(columns= None, fill_value=0)
          classifier = joblib.load('./pkl/Without.pkl')
          prediction = classifier.predict(query)
          if prediction == 0:
                 pred_text = 'Rejected'
          else:
                 pred_text = 'Approved'
          #return jsonify({'prediction': list(prediction)})
          return jsonify(result={"status": 200})
        except:
               traceback.print_exc(file = sys.stdout)
 else:
        return "none ff"
          
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Does anyone know why the "Method" is not being allowed?

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing single quote at:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET, 'POST'])
```

the decorator for `/predict` is commented. I stripped down your code to this block:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# @app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST' or 'GET':
        return "request type: {}".format(request.method)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

and this works for both GET and POST requests.